# $\pi$, from Pentadecagon - infinitely expanding Balloon nested Radical

Tags: circles, infinity, pi, polygons, nested-radicals

In this post, I would like to share the findings on derivation of $\pi$ with Pentadecagon inscribed in unit circle.

Here the side of each chord is $2\sin12^\circ$
(Bisecting the chord by segment which passes through the centre of circle, it is perpendicular to the chord)[image: Pentadecagon]

Now doubling the sides i.e for 30gon, each side of chord is $2\sin6^\circ$ which can be represented as $\sqrt{2-2\cos12^\circ}$ (by Half angle cosine formula)

For 60gon it is $2\sin3^\circ$ which can be represented as $\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+2\cos12^\circ}}$

Circumference of 60gon will be $60\cdot\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+2\cos12^\circ}}$

Approximation for $\pi$ will be $15\cdot2^1\cdot\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+2\cos12^\circ}}$

When we continue like this

For 120gon it is $2\sin1.5^\circ$ which can be represented as $\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+2\cos12^\circ}}}$

Circumference of 120gon will be $120\cdot\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+2\cos12^\circ}}}$

Approximation for $\pi$ will be $15\cdot2^2\cdot\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+2\cos12^\circ}}}$

We can generalize this to get the more and more accurate value for $\pi$ as $\pi = 15\cdot2^n\cdot\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+...\text{(n times)}+2\cos12^\circ}}}$

$\therefore$  $\pi = \lim_{n \to\infty} 15\cdot2^n\cdot\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+...\text{(n times)}+2\cos12^\circ}}}$

**Note:**

> Infinite expansion happens between right and left extremes of nested radical - (Infinite expansion of balloon nested radical)

**Interesting aspects of deriving $\pi$ with Pentadecagon inscribed in unit circle are**

1. $2\cos12^\circ$ as Infinite nested square roots of 2 as $\sqrt{2+{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-...}}}}}$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3819202/solving-infinite-nested-square-roots-of-2-converging-to-finite-nested-radical)
2. $2\cos12^\circ$ as a finite nested radical can be represented as $\frac{1}{2}\times\sqrt{9+\sqrt5+\sqrt{(30-6\sqrt5)}}$
3. Relatively faster convergence than square inscribed in unit circle giving rise to $\pi$

**Amazing thing to note is 2 infinities in single nested radical. At the right extreme, cyclic infinite nested square roots of 2 converging to $2\cos\frac{\pi}{15}$ and then another infinite expansion between the extremes of nested radical ultimately converging to $\pi$.** It is as though there is strict discipline between 2 different infinities converging to $\pi$ (pun intended). Even though both are infinitely expandable, they are countable in the strict sense, if we observe.

$\pi = \lim_{n \to\infty} 15\cdot2^n\cdot\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+...\text{(n times)}+\sqrt{2+{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-...}}}}}}}}$

> **Interestingly infinite product for $\pi$ with perspective of Pentadecagon will be as follows**

If $C = 2\cos\frac{\pi}{15}$

$$\pi = 15\cdot\sqrt{2-C}\cdot\frac{2}{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+C}}}\cdot\frac{2}{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+C}}}}...$$

Comment: Nice!! have you tried comparing this approximation with other approximations? questions like how fast do they converge, how much computation is required must be answered to understand the true potential of this approximation....:-)

Comment: Your post contains no question.